# Switch statement between functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a switch statement where each case is calling a function with a setInterval timer automatically going from case to case non-stop.

```
 var myTimer;
 switch(myTimer = setInterval(function() {
   case 1:
    auto_url();
    break;
   case 2:
    auto_url2();
    break;
   case 3:
    auto_url3();
   }, 10000);
```

Comment: do you have a special use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For calling functions in a wanted order and repeatedly, you could take an array and store an index for the access.

For each call of the callback of `setInterval`, a function is taken out of the array and called. The index is updated and adjusted for the next access.

```js
var fn1 = function () { console.log('fn1'); },
    fn2 = function () { console.log('fn2'); },
    fn3 = function () { console.log('fn3'); },
    fns = [fn1, fn2, fn3],
    index = 0,
    myTimer = setInterval(function() {
        fns[index++]();
        index %= fns.length;
    }, 1500);
```

Comment: do i replace the console.log with my function ?

Comment: auto_url1 = function () { console.log('auto_url1'); },  like this ?

Comment: i mean `fns = [auto_url1, auto_url2, auto_url3];`

Comment: Hi Nina, im trying to replace the time value with a variable so the user can input the wished interval in seconds on the popup.html. Is it possible ? i am using this to declare variable: var seconds = document.getElementById("timeValue").value; --- where timeValue is the input id of the form field

Comment: yes, but you need a factor of `1000`, because of the needed unit of milli seconds.

Comment: yes, but its not updating the interval for some reason.

Comment: the interval is set at start, you can not change the inteval length inbetween. for this purpose, you could take `setTimeout`, this runs only onece.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164829/how-to-allow-user-to-set-time-for-setinterval

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. `switch` is a statement with the following syntax:

```
switch (expr) {
  case expr:
    statements
  default:
    statements
}
```

with zero or more `case` clauses and zero or one `default` clause. Your `switch` expression swallowed the cases, so there's none for `switch`, and your `case` clauses are bare in the function without a `switch`. It is also not clear at all what you would want to switch on.

The cleanest way to rewrite your example would be to use a lookup object:

```
const lookup = {
  1: auto_url1,
  2: auto_url2,
  3: auto_url3,
};

let which = 1;
func = lookup[which];
if (func === undefined) {
  console.error("Bad which.");
} else {
  let myTimer = setInterval(lookup[which], 10000);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i cant call functions in a switch statement ?

Comment: You can call functions in both the switch expression, and in the statements. You can't define a function inside a switch expression that would contain the switch's cases.

Comment: No im declaring the functions outside the switch, i just need to call them as im trying to do in the code above. Do i just need to arrange the cases to 1,2, default for example?

Comment: I am referring to the anonymous function that is the callback of your `setInterval`, not the `auto_url` functions.

Comment: aa yes i knew it wasnt going to work like that, just wanted to show what i wanted to do. In your edited example, what do i need to put where you left the commented dots? or should it work like that ?